# Kohana "Один ко многим"

Tags: php, kohana

Еще раз добрый вечер, существует проблема, при связи один ко многим, в таблицу заносятся пустые строки, в чем может быть проблема, может быть кто-то сталкивался?

Код к примеру такой:
Controller:

```
$user->educations->user_personal_id = $id;
$user->educations->faculty = "smp";
$user->educations->save();
```

Model:

```
 class Model_User_personal extends ORM 
    {
        protected $_has_many = array(
                    'educations' => array(
                        'model' => 'user_education',
                    ),
                    'works' => array(
                        'model' => 'user_work',
                    ),
                );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

в ORM есть метов add(). Работает так:

```
$var = ORM::factory('your_model');
// передаём в модель данные
$var->values($data_array);
// сохраняем модель
// при сохранении модель, по умолчанию, возвращает id вставленной строки
try
{
  $var->save()l
} catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
  // do smth if error
}    
// добавляем в выбранную модель те самые значения по связи
$var->add('alias_name', $value);
```

// где alias_name - это имя связи, а $value - значение